# How to get all embedded items within document collection?

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb

I've been stuck on this problem for a couple of days now. I'm trying to do the following:

Consider the following C# classes that correspond to the documents in MongoDB. Merchants are stored in a merchant collection and all contain an array of Currencies.

```
class Merchant
{
    public string id {get;set;}
    public List<Currency> MerchantCurrencies {get; set; }
}

class Currency
{
    public string id {get; set; }
    public string name {get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Now, what I want to do, is to return all the currencies of all merchants within a single query with LINQ. I've tried things like SelectMany and multiple from clauses, like this:

```
var currencies = merchantCollection.AsQueryable()
.SelectMany(m => m.MerchantCurrencies)
.Where(ccy => ccy.CurrencyState == currencyStatus)
.OrderBy(ccy => ccy.CurrencyName);
```

and

```
var currencies= from merch in merchantCollection.AsQueryable()
from ccy in merch.MerchantCurrencies
select ccy
```

However, all those things don't work since they are based on SelectMany which uses joins. The use of SelectMany will throw an exception as it's not supported by the MongoDB C# driver.

Is there any solution to my problem, apart from using aggregation framework / map reduce / multiple queries?

The only solution I found, was:
1. Getting all merchants
2. Loop over the merchants
3. Loop over their currencies
4. Add currencies to another list variable

However, I do not like this approach because I'd have to get all the merchant objects which is a pretty expensive operation if it's a huge collection.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to use a NoSQL database to store relational data, which might not be a good idea. If you want to stick to MongoDB, I would recommend adding a new collection of all the different currencies and updating it as necessary.

Check out this link to [MongoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/model-data-for-ruby-on-rails/), which describes the same problem.

> MongoDB does not support joins and so, at times, requires bit of denormalization. MongoDB collections are not equivalent to relational tables; each serves a unique design objective. A normalized table provides an atomic, isolated chunk of data. A document, however, more closely represents an object as a whole.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, but unfortunately, it won't work. SelectMany's internal implementation uses joins to combine multiple tables. Joins do not exist in MongoDB. The use of SelectMany will thus throw an exception when used. I've tried that one already.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part about your question which dealt with the joins in MongoDB. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer : I know 0 about c# and LINQ

However, there is a built-in function for doing what you want: [`distinct`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/). Per the disclaimer I'll illustrate in the mongo shell:

```
> db.test.drop()
> db.test.insert({ "a" : [{ "a" :1 , "b" : 2 }, "op", 2, "3", "goop"] })
> db.test.insert({ "a" : [1,2, 3, "goop"] })
> db.test.distinct("a")
[ 1, 2, 3, "goop", "3", "op", { "a" : 1, "b" : 2 } ]
> db.test.distinct("a", { "a" : "op" })
[ 2, "3", "goop", "op", { "a" : 1, "b" : 2 } ]
```

It does your 1-4 but on the server-side, essentially - there can be no other way to get the distinct values of documents unless the work has already been partially done because there's an index. If you have an index on `{ "a" : 1 }` in the above example, `distinct` can use that to find the distinct values with an index scan instead of a collection scan.

I think the C# method you want is [this one](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/Overload_MongoDB_Driver_MongoCollection_Distinct.htm).

Comment: Your answer seems plausible, but do you know how to further reduce the results? Like, when you receive the distincts, I want to further narrow the elements eg. by querying them by name. Do you know how to do this? So something like db.merchants.distinct("merchantcurrencies").find({"name: <term>});